# Share document in iOS app

Tags: ios, frameworks, share, document

I have a requirement to sharing files (PDF,PPT,Word etc.) from my App, I know we can get them from Drop Box, Google Drive, Box, iCloud etc..

Is there any SDK provided by iOS which we can handle locally with out downloading other Framework. For example the new WhatsApp feature having the share document.

The UI and all seems to be from Native SDK, how can we access it ?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Where is this sharing to be initiated? Is the sharing started by the user while using your app and they wish to open a specific file in some other app? Or is the sharing to be started from some other app and the user needs to choose a file from some other source such as iCloud, Dropbox, and your app's files?

Comment: I need to open from installed Apps, If dropbox is installed i need to access from it, Same as Whats App functionality for share document, in the new versions

Comment: So the user is running your app and they wish to get a file from Dropbox, iCloud, etc. Correct? If so, use `UIDocumentPickerViewController` and `UIDocumentMenuViewController`.

Comment: Thanks will check it, Is it for only iCloud or It is Applicable for other Apps as well

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pickup documents to your application, you can see `UIDocumentPickerViewController` and `UIDocumentMenuViewController`

Take a look at :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentPickerViewController_Class/
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentMenuViewController_Class/

---

You have to make a `Share extension`, then if the user has those apps, the extension will be able to easily share your contents.

Take a look at : 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH12-SW1

---

If your documents are from a known source and have to be downloaded and uploaded, you also can do a `Document provider extension`.

Take a look at :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/FileProvider.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH18-SW1

Comment: Based on the comments, I don't think this is what the OP is asking about.